# Display Content inside Right DIV-section based On Filter Search

Tags: javascript, php, html

The general idea here is to filter various product categories and then to display the content (product grid) of the chosen category inside the right DIV-section.

As of now, as a "dummy" version, the right DIV is just text. The right DIV has an ID and my question is this: how to display content inside it?

The idea is to have functions that fetch, from the database, products from each category (all from each category) and then to display that inside the right DIV-section.

I hope you all understand me?

**This is the code so far:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create a column layout with Flexbox */
.row {
  display: flex;
}

/* Left column (menu) */
.left {
  flex: 35%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.left h2 {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Right column (page content) */
.right {
  flex: 65%;
  padding: 15px;
}

/* Style the search box */
#mySearch {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Style the navigation menu inside the left column */
#myMenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myMenu li a {
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block
}

#myMenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Search Menu</h2>
<p>Start to type for a specific category inside the search bar to "filter" the search options.</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="left" style="background-color:#333;">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
    <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#">Clothes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Toys</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Misc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right" id="contentDIV" style="background-color:#eee;">
    <h2>Menu Content</h2>
    <p>Start to type for a specific category inside the search bar to "filter" the search options.</p>
    <p>This will later be the content section for those categories.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ajax will help you to achieve your query

Comment: can you please add fiddle ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask

To fetch data from a database, you will need a "backend", code that runs directly on the server, and can read the database to send you what you need. That can be done with php, with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/), or many other languages.

To actually get the data to your frontend, i.e. the code run in the browser, you can use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) function from javascript, or a library called [Axios](https://axios-http.com/), which makes a little bit easier.

The code bellow should give you a pretty good start, but the backend if fake, of course. If you don't want to set up one yourself, you can mimic it with open API's, like [NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org/)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Create a column layout with Flexbox */
    
    .row {
      display: flex;
    }
    /* Left column (menu) */
    
    .left {
      flex: 35%;
      padding: 15px 0;
    }
    
    .left h2 {
      padding-left: 8px;
    }
    /* Right column (page content) */
    
    .right {
      flex: 65%;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    /* Style the search box */
    
    #mySearch {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 11px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    /* Style the navigation menu inside the left column */
    
    #myMenu {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #myMenu li a {
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myMenu li a:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #333;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Search Menu</h2>
  <p>Start to type for a specific category inside the search bar to "filter" the search options.</p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="left" style="background-color:#333;">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      <input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
      <ul id="myMenu">
        <li><a href="#" id="Clothes">Clothes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="Cars">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="Toys">Toys</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="Electronics">Electronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="Misc">Misc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="right" id="contentDIV" style="background-color:#eee;">
      <h2>Menu Content</h2>
      <p id="content">Start to type for a specific category inside the search bar to "filter" the search options.</p>
      <p>This will later be the content section for those categories.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        //Add the click event to the a's
        a.addEventListener('click', updateContent)

        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }

    async function updateContent(event) {
      const content = document.querySelector('#content')
      const response = await getDataFromBackend(event.target.id)
      content.innerText = response.body
    }

    async function getDataFromBackend(category) {
      return await axios.get(`http://mybackend/api/${category}`)

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```